# How to use 'OS Sampler' of jmeter to run any command of terminal on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to change system date using terminal from j-meter for which i am using "OS sampler".

I want to run: 'sudo date --set "2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"' command in terminal using OS sampler.

But it is not working.

Under OS sampler fields i have tried - 'nohup' in command box, '/home/test4' in working directory field, and 'sudo date --set "2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"' in command parameters.

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRrx.png)

Please correct me what wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution!!!

Create one bash file and write below command

echo -e "(password_of_your_system)\n" | sudo -S date --set "2020-03-09 07:00:00"

[Click here for bash file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19MxA.png)

Save the bash file and move the file to the location where you jmx file is saved.

Now go to jmeter >> OS Sampler and do the settings as displaying in below screenshot.

[Click here for OS Sampler settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa86I.png)

Command: /bin/bash

Working dir: Path of your jmx file.

Command parameter: your bash file with extension .sh

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) as a wrapper for your command like:

[image]

and hopefully you know what you're doing as if you change operating system date somewhere in the middle of the test JMeter sampler [timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) will be impacted and you will have hard time analyzing test results.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)